# Make a Column to have padding-right and padding-left 0 with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Goal:
Make a specific column to have padding-right and padding-left to have value 0. The remaining of the column in the table should not be affected

Problem:
I have tried with different solution but it doesn't go so well.

Any idea?

Thank you!

```
Demo:  http://jsbin.com/kinoqobuno/edit?html,output
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to change the thead > td, but you use a thead > th! please change your css to the following:

```
#ddd thead tr th:nth-child(1){
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;  
}
```